# Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I just moved from php to asp.net. I'm trying to deploy a very basic mvc 3 application to my hosting provider. After it deploys, I visit the website, and it displays:

**Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is "1.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "2.0.0.0". To continue, remove files from the application's bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config.**

I'm not sure where to look. Its the 'out of the box' mvc 3 application with no modification.  I tried to use this method, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896878/conflicting-versions-of-asp-net-web-pages-detected-specified-version-is-1-0-0" but had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set webpages:Version appSettings with appropriate value. In your case it has to be 2.0.0.0

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This was very useful, thanks so much. I was trying to resolve this issue with MonoDevelop while creating a basic Mvc3 project.

Comment: useful information, however, the <appsettings> cannot be the first element inside <configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link, you would probably have to check the assembly version in bin directory

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/11/conflicting-versions-of-aspnet-web.html

Comment: I've read that link before I posted and it didnt help. Maybe because I didnt understand. I dont have a System.Web.WebPages.Deployment deployment. I'm also confused with the target framework. It's set to 4.0. What's the difference between the wepages version and the target framework?

Comment: You can try removing one dll at a time in your bin folder and check if it works.

Comment: It only does this when I publish the site. it doesnt happen on the development server...

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried the above solutions and are still getting the same problem then try this one->
Go to your project folder and in there locate the *bin* folder --> Remove *System.Web.Mvc.dll* and *System.Web.Mvc.xml* from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in webmatrix, to solve it I had to go to settings and update ASP.NET web pages version from 1.0 to 2.0