# Runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, runtime-error

I tinkered with my ASP.NET MVC4 packages via NuGet, and now `System.Web.WebPages.Razor v3` won't load.  Sometimes other packages won't load either.

My coworker runs the solution without any trouble, so the issue is definitely configuration on my development system (as opposed to anything that's been checked in).

I have already tried the recommendations at various SOf and other fora links, including:

- [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124103/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-2-0-0-0?rq=1)
- [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-2-0-0-0)
- [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763039/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-3-0-0-0)

As well as suggestions linked from there.  I also checked the Control Panel and found no installed programs that referenced MVC.  (If it matters, I'm running MS Win 7 SP 1.)

I am open to any and all suggestions.

Here's my core dump info:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> ```
> Source Error: 
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> ```
>
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> ```
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
> ```
>
> Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>       LOG: User = CodesWithHammer
>       LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>        (Fully-specified)
>       LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/users/CodesWithHammer/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/MPP/MPP/
>       LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\users\CodesWithHammer\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\MPP\MPP\bin
>       Calling assembly : Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>
> ===
>       LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>       LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\users\CodesWithHammer\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\MPP\MPP\web.config
>       LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\CodesWithHammer\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>       LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>       LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/CodesWithHammer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/5bf3ca07/f960d9c5/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/CodesWithHammer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/5bf3ca07/f960d9c5/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/CodesWithHammer/documents/visual studio
>   2012/Projects/MPP/MPP/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/CodesWithHammer/documents/visual studio
>   2012/Projects/MPP/MPP/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/CodesWithHammer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/5bf3ca07/f960d9c5/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/CodesWithHammer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/5bf3ca07/f960d9c5/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/CodesWithHammer/documents/visual studio
>   2012/Projects/MPP/MPP/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/CodesWithHammer/documents/visual studio
>   2012/Projects/MPP/MPP/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.EXE.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.]
>          Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> ```
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
>   exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified..]
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1
>   methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +550
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +132
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath) +90
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
>          System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
>   exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified..]
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874840
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

(For those who read this far:  I don't have enough reputation to make the tag **pulling-out-my-hair**.  If there's an appropriate extant tag, please include that.  KTHX.)

ETA:  When I tried manually updating `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` to version 3, here's the error I got on Package Manager Console:

> Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Updating
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 3.0.20105.1'
>   failed. Unable to find a version of
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes' that is compatible wi th
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 3.0.20105.1'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

ETA2:  I got the packages directory from my coworker.  They have `MS.AspNet.Mvc` v5, and they're running just fine.  But they ALSO have `MS.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes` v5.  So I'm going to add both of those in.  And yes, I have backed up my entire solution. :)

ETA3:  So I re-upgraded to AspNet MVC v5, and skipped the deprecated Mvc.FixedDisplayNodes.  Then I got a problem with conflicting versions of AspNet.WebPages, so I used this fix:  [Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is "1.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "2.0.0.0" in ASP.MET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892868/mvc3-conflicting-versions-of-asp-net-web-pages-detected-specified-version-is)

And now my project runs!

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Did you tried `clean` and then `rebuild` your solution? Problem is that you most likely updated from MVC4 to MVC5 via nuget.

Comment: I repeatedly `clean`ed and `rebuild`t.  I don't see any MVC5 packages, but I'll n-tuple check.

Answer (score 38):

You can find it in Nuget Package Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages Version 3.2.0

[image: Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages]

If you have a reference to an earlier version than 3.0.0.0, Delete the reference, add the reference to the correct .dll in your packages folder and make sure "Copy Local" is set to "True" in the properties of the .dll.

Then in your web.config (as mentioned by @MichaelEvanchik)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Yes,  this works for the error  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0

Comment: Yes, It's Works bro.
Thank you so much for support. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 24):

```
"Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages"
```

Reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages nuget packages using this command in the package manager console.

Comment: Is there any way to bookmark a comment? because this is fantastic, and this problem has plagued me far too often!

Comment: @user3654055 here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959406/runtime-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-versi#answer-34923294

Answer (score 4):

same thing JUST happened to me with NUGET.

the following tag helped

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Also if this is happening on the server, I had to make sure I was running the application pool on a more "privileged account" to the file system, but I don think that's your issue here

Comment: Are you sure about oldVersion 1 through **4**?  I'm just double checking as I know what it's like to have a one character tpyo.

Comment: It's a bad advice. First of all, he's already trying to load v3, and can't find that, so there's no reason to redirect to v3. And it's a bad idea to redirect an assembly to an older version in general. Redirecting from v3 to v4 does make sense though, it is even officially supported I think.

Comment: I edited it before you even put your comment in.  The reason is the issue I had was with and was with System.Web.Mvc as I didn't use Razor so I was trying to create the tag manually above for you

its funny how this answer isn't acceptable here, but I got the accepted answer.....from here

Answer (score 2):

in the new actionmailer, "razorengine" is a dependency. The latest version of Razorengine installs the dependency to System.Web.Razor 3.0.0.

If you use an earlier version in your application (i suppose you are using actionmailer in another project and that you reference the mail functionality from another project) than you get this issue of course.

In an earlier application, i had a webapplication MVC that uses system.web.Razor version 2.0.0.
Of course, i got the issue to. 
How to fix?
=> Simple!

1. Just uninstall the entire actionmailer in your actionmailer project.
2. Install a previous version of RazorEngin

> Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.3.0 (because version 3.3.0 will reference system.web.razor 2.0.0)
>
> Install actionmailer again (it will not install the latest version of RazorEngin because you allready did that yourselve)
>
> Succes!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll in the bin folder of your web app? What is its version? (Explorer right click, properties) I'm guessing it's not 3.0.0.0. Just get the nuget packages for v3.0.0.0, perhaps by copying the packages folder from your colleague. Or install it manually: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.20105.1

EDIT: if you copy stuff from your colleague, also copy the relevant version numbers into packages.config. This is what tells nuget which versions to put into the packages folder.

Comment: I copied `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll` v2.0.0.0 into my bin directory from PFx86/.../, there was no change.  I'll remove all the DLLs and XMLs, and copy over what my colleague has.  When I tried updating `MS.AspNet.Mvc` from NuGet, I got problems; let me go try again and copy in the error message.

Comment: Don't bother with copying DLL's manually, Visual Studio will always win :). Make sure you have the right version of the DLL in your packages folder (that's what nuger does), make sure that exact DLL is referenced in your project (nuget also handles it I think, but maybe you can accidentally edit that reference), and that's it.

Comment: Hmm.  MS.AN.Mvc is at v5.  I'll try your link.

Comment: Hmm again.  There are no relevant packages that require updates at this time.  But last time I checked, `System.Web.Razor` in my project references only listed versions 1 and 2.  I know 3 used to be there somewhere.

Comment: Don't update your packages because it will upgrade MVC 3 to 5. Use the package manager console to get the exact version. Or as I said, if it's working for your colleague, just copy over his folder and then don't worry about nuget.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like.  I just downgraded MVC from 5 to 3; now I'm getting compile errors on `Mvc.Mailer v1` referencing MVC 4.  (Mvc.Mailer is used by SecurityGuard.)  MVC3 also didn't like `using System.Web.Mvc.Filters` in my password expiration attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to install visual studio and development environment, so I have installed AspNetMVC4Setup.exe in Windows server 2016 machine and it solved the problem. The installer was downloaded from Microsoft website.

[image: File properties of the installer]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue didn't resolve by following any of the above methods. I had all the paths in my package config correct and the dll's were in place as referred, I was still getting run time error for System.Web.WebPages.Razor.  **`I changed the localhost port number and this worked`**

I am not sure of why I had the issue and why changing the port number resolved it. Just posting this as I feel this might be useful for someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was not about binding redirects or missing/mismatched Microsoft.AspNet.Razor package/dlls, so the above solutions didn't work.

The issue, in my non-web project, was that RazorEngine+Microsoft.AspNet.Razor were installed in a **different project (Project A) than the calling assembly/start-up project (Project B)**. Because there's no explicit reference to Razor, the **System.Web.Razor did NOT get copied to /bin** in a Release build.

The solution was to **Install RazorEngine+Microsoft.AspNet.Razor in the application entry point** (Project B, ConsoleApplication in my case), then the System.Web.Razor gets copied to /bin and everyone's happy.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, what worked for me is:

1. Fix references error.
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. Delete Packages.
4. Delete .vs folder.
5. Run Project Again.
6. Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because I uninstalled VS 2012, I don't want to reinstall it back, so I downloaded the AspNetMVC4Setup.exe from Microsoft.com and fixed my problem.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I upgraded to v3.0.0.preview4, so a downgrade to a stable version fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because such DLL (and many others) were missing in bin folder when I pubished the web application. It seemed like a bug in Visual Studio publish function. Cleaning, recompiling and publishing it again, made such DLLs to be published correctly.