# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, owin

I have a MVC project with OAuth authentication, every time I try to debug the project i get a FileLoadException upon configuring the IAppBuilder. I have installed version 3.0.1 of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Oauth using the PMC but I guess somewhere still lies a reference to an older version of the package because...

This is the exception:

[image]

This is where it is thrown:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app); //Exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

This is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I tried adding [binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868287/1376691) as such:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

*Can´t understand why this doesn´t work, does Visual Studio make a difference between 3.0.1 and 3.0.1.0?*

I tried removing obj and bin folders, cleaning projects and rebuilding them.

I tried deleting all nuget packages and restoring them.

I tried reinstalling all Owin packages.

I´ve used Agent Ransack to search my entire source directory for any file containing *Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth* but found no references to version 2.0.0.0 or any other version besides the correct 3.0.1.0.

I´m stuck, any ideas?

Comment: adding to `packages.config` is not enough, did you add a reference to that dll in your `.cproj` file?

Comment: check to see if there is a Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll in your bin folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding to packages.config is not enough"? Do you propose that I install it using the package manager console and then in addition add the reference manually? What would be the point of that? And yeah, the 3.0.1 version of the DLL is in the Bin folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so just in case anyone else ends up with this problem;

The problem was that the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` package is depending on `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` and there was a mismatch in version.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Apparently, even though [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/1.0.0) requires >= v2.0 of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`, having v3+ of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` will break the compatibility (major version inconsistency).

After I had updated `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` package and its adjacent family members `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` I removed all packages, bin and obj folders and rebuilt solution. Voila!

A tip to the VS2013+ Ultimate user is to use the NuGet Package Visualizer when exploring package dependencies.

Comment: Can you please correct the the quoted text: "even though Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin requires >= v2.0 of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, having v3+ of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin"

Answer (score 0):

Check your references. Remove the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth from everywhere, then restore all nuget packages.